# eclipse photon screen render issue

Tags: eclipse

I installed Eclipse Photon on Ubuntu 16.04 and I am getting screen artefacts after screen refreshes, for example as can be seen in the attached image after a text search.

Searching for solutions is not resulting in anything useful.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you work with:

```
SWT_GTK3=0
```

when starting Eclipse on you 16.04 Ubuntu.

In this case try:

```
SWT_GTK3=1
```

Regards,
Mark

Comment: you may be on the right track. I can't say it's fixed yet, but I can see differences. Give me a few days to verify and I will accept if all works.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 25
Added into eclipse.ini

```
--launcher.GTK_version
3
```

It is fixed mess.